# Planet filter file for ENVI atmospheric correction

Tags: envi, planet, atmospheric-correction

I have 4 band Planet Scope multispectral imagery that I am trying to process in ENVI.  It is the analytic data, so it is already radiometrically corrected.  I have converted the .tif to a BIL, and done the band specific calculations to get TOA reflectance (from the metadata).  I want to do the FLAASH atmospheric correction, but in the hyperspectral tab of the FLAASH window, it requires a filter function file that is specific to the sensor being used. Usually, with a known sensor, this filter function file gets automatically uploaded because ENVI saves .hdr and .sli files of many known sensors. I have ENVI 5.3 (and dont have the capabilities to upgrade).  In ENVI 5.5 they include the Planet Scope sensor and its filter details.

Does anyone know how to create a filter file for planet scope, and/or the format required for the file?

Comment: This is actually a question, rather than an answer, but how did you convert the .tif to a BIL? And did you finally manage to do the FLAASH? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

FLAASH atmospheric correction for landsat data must be done based on these steps:

1. open mtl file.
2. enter radiometric calibration command.
3. select multispectral data.
4. choose the apply flaash settings.
5. save the radiance image.
6. open radiance image in flaash and do it.

good luck